# Why do undefined parameters in an if statement not cause a segfault or another error?

Tags: c++, if-statement

For Example:

```
array[2]={1,2};
myInt=5;

if (array[myInt-6]==2)
   cout << true << endl;
else
   cout << false << endl;
```

The referenced value in the array in the if statement is clearly out of bounds. When I compile and run this I get false outputted which makes sense as the condition is not true, but I'm wondering why theres no error outputted.

Comment: There is no requirement for undefined behaviour to give any specific results. Mostly the compiler goes with what's easiest. Here "what's easiest" for your system happens to look sort of like working until you look closely. A different day/implementation/run might do something different. Undefined is undefined.

Comment: If you want bounds checking use std::vector. Rather than using `operator[]` use the method `at()` it will validate the index you use and make sure it is in range.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because **undefined behavior is undefined**. Anything can happen, including appearing to work.

A diagnostic isn't required of the compiler nor the runtime. You have to take care of bound checking by yourself.

Comment: In javascript, I believe if (undefined) evaluates to false, is this the case with C++ as well?

Comment: @bobnargot no, undefined behavior means something entirely different in C++. It's not an undefined variable, it's behavior of a program that is undefined by the standard, so any result or behavior is correct.

Comment: @bobnargot JavaScript has a special value named `undefined` (oh but WHY?). Name it `foobargl` and nothing changes. C++ has the concept of undefined behaviour, that really means the behaviour is undefined. It's not a value with well-defined (even if crazy) behaviour that happens to be named `undefined`. You can't say it's foobargl behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not a [memory-safe language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Safely_and_unsafely_typed_systems), so it's your job to avoid such problems, not the compiler's or runtime's.

Next question.

Comment: If you used a vector and .at() rather than a raw array it would give you an exception. C++ is memory safe (where you need it) if you ask it to be

Comment: @MartinBeckett, no, it's not. "Memory-safe" in this context has a specific meaning: the language does not *allow* errors to occur. "The programmer can choose to check bounds in code either explicitly or implicitly" does not count.

Comment: yes it's not "memory safe" but it at least gives you a chance!

Answer (score -4):

Calling `array[-1]` isn't an error, it's pretty much just shorthand for `*(array - 1)` i.e. the value at the address one int before array. Assuming the OS has allocated this address to your program, you'll just get some random bit of data cast to an int.

Because the data stored at that location is likely to be the same each time, you'll get the same behavior - it just won't make a whole lot of sense. If you want to force things like this to result in an error, it's probably easiest to use one of the Standard Template Library's containers e.g. [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)

Comment: no. you have the right sort of thinking, but the key point here is that accessing and index out of bounds is UB, and as such can do what ever it wants, including ordering you some pizza

Comment: Sure, array[-1] is not an "error" here, but it could legitimately rip a hole in the space-time continuum, destroying the universe and rendering the conversation moot.  See above comments.